# JSFiddle not executing my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am a student and learning to code. I have downloaded this simple HTML Javascript code from internet. It moves an image across the screen by pressing the 4 arroww keys. This works fine on browser, but does not work on JSFiddle. I am a beginner student. This question has been asked on the forums. I looked at the answers but it did not solve my problem.

Answers that I got from the forum was:

- Do a Javascript "no wrap head" - did not work for me
- Change "function" syntax - did not work for me

Any help thanks and appreciated:

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ThatBoyCoder/s85wtqL3/

<------ Code ------->

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Test Move Object</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                function leftArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 25 + 'px';
                }

                function rightArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 25 + 'px';
                }

                function upArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 25 + 'px';
                }

                function downArrowPressed() {
                var element = document.getElementById("image1");
                element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 25 + 'px';
                }

                function moveSelection(evt) {
                    switch (evt.keyCode) {

                case 37:
                            leftArrowPressed();
                            break;

                case 39:
                            rightArrowPressed();
                            break;

                case 38:
                            upArrowPressed();
                            break;

                case 40:
                            downArrowPressed();
                            break;
                        }
                    };

            function domReady()
                {
                        window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
                }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="domReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="" bgcolor='yellow'>
        Test
    <img id="image1" src="http://placekitten.com/69/69" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="50" width="50">
    </body>
        end html
        </html>
```

Comment: Works just fine for me.

Comment: it works well on the jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks Xufox, Kris. It is working now. I was not clicking on the runtime window after pressing "Run" on JSFiddle.

Comment: You could set the focus to the window explicitly with `window.focus()`: https://jsfiddle.net/s85wtqL3/1/

Comment: Thanks nn. That was very helpful